# How can I set up my headless Ubuntu $DISPLAY to a local network Windows 11 PC display?

Tags: headless

I am very confused about X server/client and got many errors that I could not solve, nor the community here (maybe). My main goal is to have a seamless GUI integration, just like when working over Windows Subsystem for Linux 2.
That is, I want to interact with my Ubuntu apps from my Windows 11 computer.

Comment: you have to install an X server on the Windows PC, allow connections from all sources or specifically from the Linux server's IP, and possibly modify firewall rules in Windows to allow the connection. Then you can configure the $DISPLAY variable in Linux to point to the IP of the Windows device

Comment: and we certainly can not solve errors if we don't know what they are!

Comment: *"got many errors that I could not solve"* -- If you want help with this, we need you to copy/paste the errors alongside the exact steps needed to reproduce them. Questions without clear, actionable details are unlikely to be answered. We don't even know what version of Ubuntu you are using. And it's not even clear what you want to do. Ubuntu on WSL is not "headless" so what do you mean? See: [How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). For a more detailed writeup on asking effectively: http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints --Help us help you